# Django Rest Framework: serializing/deserializing a calculated field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just started using Django & Django REST framework. I have the following models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    vat_perc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return "ACCOUNT: {0} -- {1}".format(self.name, str(self.vat_perc))


class Entry(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    taxable_income = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        selected_vat = Account.objects.get(pk=self.account).vat_perc
        self.total_amount = self.taxable_income * (100.00+selected_vat)/100.00
        super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The idea would be to read the `vat_perc` value inside the `account` record the user has just selected and to perform a calculation to determine the `total_amount` value which then should be saved in the `entry` record on the database (I know some would regard this as suboptimal due to the duplication of data in the database; please follow me anyway).

The `total_amount` field should be regularly serialized when requested. Instead, the serializer should not do anything for deserialization, because the overriding of the `save` method in the model takes care of updating values if a creation or modification occurs. If I get the documentation correctly, all this means setting the `total_amount` field in the serializer class as `read_only`.

Now, these are my serializers:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'vat_perc',)


class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('id', 'account', 'description', 'taxable_income', 'total_amount',)

    total_amount = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    # alternatively: total_amount = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)
```

But this is the error I get:

> Got a `TypeError` when calling `Entry.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Entry.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the EntrySerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
>   Original exception text was: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Account'.

The last sentence sounds particularly obscure to me. Am I getting something wrong? Any hint? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you could profit from having a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: Thanks @Claudiu. Your comment did not give me the answer, but it led me to it. There was a bunch of things I was still missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [Claudiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569343/claudiu). Used `SlugRelatedField` in the serializer class and `decimal.Decimal`type instead of `float` as I did mistankenly. The following code now works:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    vat_perc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return "ACCOUNT: {0} -- {1}".format(self.name, str(self.vat_perc))


class Entry(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    taxable_income = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_amount = self.taxable_income * (decimal.Decimal(100.00) + self.account.vat_perc) / decimal.Decimal(100.00)
        super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Account
         fields = ('id', 'name', 'vat_perc',)


class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('id', 'account', 'description', 'taxable_income', 'total_amount',)

    total_amount = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    account = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Account.objects.all(), slug_field="vat_perc")
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it out! Maybe I can suggest making this the accepted answer, as soon as you're able to do it.